# Android - RadioButton and CheckBox in same ListView item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, radio-button, android-linearlayout

I've found a few examples of adding a RadioButton or a CheckBox to a ListView.  I've even found one that uses one or the other depending on whether the ListView allows multiselect or not.

What I'm trying to do is have a RadioButton followed by a CheckBox.  If the RadioButton is selected, all other RadioButtons should clear, and all CheckBoxes should clear.  If a CheckBox is selected, all RadioButtons should clear, but I should be able to select more CheckBoxes on my own.

In other words, it's multiselect and singleselect just depending on the user's preference.

I created a class for the linearlayout with both views and a TextView.  I am using the toggle, and setChecked methods.  But I can't tell which view actually was pressed on, just that the LinearLayout was pressed.

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable 
{}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Listener for your radiobuttons and in onClick() loop through all of your checkBoxes and call `checkBox.setSelected(false)`. That will take care of clearing all checks when a radio button is chosen. Then make a seperate Listener for your check boxes and inside the onClick() of that find the radioButton that is selected and call `radioBtn.setSelected(false)`
Make sure your radio buttons are in a RadioGroup and that will handle making sure that only one of them can be selected for you without having to do anything extra.

Comment: How can I loop this?  From what I've read and tested, the list items are recycled, so I can only access what is visible on the screen at one time.

Comment: Thanks!  From some other searching, I've found I can loop visible items with getFirstVisiblePosition() and getChildCount().  I then set a variable in my list adapter that could store the state of everything.  I modify this variable in the onClick listener's and also use it during getView() to default them.  It's now working.  Thanks for pointing me in the right area.